# Change property type in Silverstripe YAML

Tags: silverstripe

I am needing to change a private static property set on a class in Silverstripe. The initial value of the property is set to a boolean. I can change the value in my _config.php file with the following

```
Config::inst()->remove('class_name', 'property');
Config::inst()->update('class_name', 'property', []);
```

What is the proper syntax to achieve the above using my _conf.yml configuration? I would like to avoid spreading out my configuration amongst multiple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the config.yml file you should do the following:

```
class_name:
  property: string-value
```

or if it is an array:

```
class_name:
  property:
    - one
    - two
```

I think what you are asking is how to replace the casting of the static, I think you might only be able to do that as you have in your example above as the yml config only sets existing config values rather than changes their structure.